# pip -U url keeps reinstalling the tar.gz package

Tags: python, url, pip

In my project I need to install a python tarball package using pip from an external url over http (this is not github nor any other VCS so the -e option is not valid).

A simple command that I run is:

```
python install http://my.repo.com/mypackage-0.1.2.tar.gz
```

although I rather use a requirements file with several packages.

Because of some automatization on a client's stage server the install command is triggered every hour with the -U option. Unfortunately even though the package I mention has not been changed it is still reinstalling on every update. It looks like pip is not aware of the currently installed package version so it keeps trying to update it.

I tried a few combinations:

```
python install -U  http://my.repo.com/mypackage-0.1.2.tar.gz
python install -U http://my.repo.com/mypackage-0.1.2.tar.gz#egg=mypackage
python install -U http://my.repo.com/mypackage-0.1.2.tar.gz#egg=mypackage==0.1.2
```

but it doesn't take any effect.

Does anyone know what I can do to avoid reinstalling the package?